# Recommendation to avoid wood beams to get rotten and break

Tags: carpentry, moisture, carport

I'm trying to see what can I do to avoid my carport to fall apart.
When I bought the house two years ago I noticed that the wood beams that supported the cover for my carport were getting wet close to the edge of the metal sheet cover every time it rains or the snow is melting. I didn't put to much attention to that but I have noticed that some parts of the wood are getting broken and I don't want the whole cover to fall down. I'm trying to look for ideas on how to fix this issue.

I was thinking in installing another metal sheet in between the wood beams and the current metal sheet to keep the water out of the wood beams, but I'm not sure what kind of metal sheet would be good in this case.

I'm attaching two pictures, in the second one you might noticed that the wood is stained due to the moisture.

[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Construction using steel square tube is unusual. By the house on the left in the 2nd pic, I'd guess you're in the suburbs in the US somewhere, is that correct? Can you get another pic showing where the damaged wood is? Is the carport roof sloped or flat? If sloped, by how much (how tall on one side v the other side)?

Comment: Hi @FreeMan, yes I'm in the suburbs in the US, the damaged wood you can see it in the second picture I shared, it got a greenish stain and it going to get worse. and as you can see from the second picture the carport roof is sloped just a little bit. I would say 10 degrees. I haven't measured one side and the other but once I do it I can post it here.

Comment: That whole thing looks like it was thrown together out of whatever materials the previous homeowner had to hand.

Comment: "Greenish stains" vary. Some are decay, some are copper oxides from pressure treated wood. I can't even find the stained part in your picture, much less tell which sort it might be. But in general, keeping them dry is the way to avoid decay, particularly if not pressure treated.

Comment: Paint. ... ... ...

Comment: @SimonB not sure,

Comment: So anything that I can install on these?

Comment: - @Mazura comment is to Paint it - not that the stain is paint.  The only damage, "broke", that you have confirm is the stain.  Unless the wood has dry rot in it,  coating the wood with paint, would provide protection from moisture.